# How can i upload file from react native to .net core api

Tags: react-native, .net-core

I tried to use form data and react-native-document-picker

```
    const config = {
      onUploadProgress: function(progressEvent) {
        var percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
        console.log(percentCompleted)
      }
    }
    let data = new FormData()
    data.append('serviceType_id', values.service_type);
    data.append('birthadate', values.birthdate);
    data.append('gender', values.gender);
    data.append('requiredFile',JSON.parse(values.files));

    try{
      console.log('try');

      const response = await axios.post(`${API_ENDPOINT}/api/vendor/new`, data, {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    }, config);
```

and my api with .net core:

```
 public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Vendor>> Post([FromBody]VendorCreateViewModel Vendor)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

```
  public class VendorCreateViewModel
  {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "serviceType_id is required")]
        public int serviceType_id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "birthadate is required")]
        public DateTime birthadate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "gender is required")]
        public gender gender { get; set; }

        //  [Required(ErrorMessage = "gender is required")]
        public IFormFile requiredFile { get; set; }
   }
```

[image: Here is my request]

then i got :

```
Error: Request failed with status code 415
```

and other question is

**How can i upload audio from react native to my api ?**

Comment: It looks like wrong format sent. Have you tried to use [rn-fetch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob) or [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) to upload file?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a basic class with a string property to store your payload (value.files)

Then in the javscript create this basic property and populate the string in a serailised format of some kind.

On the server in the .net core code deserialise this data accordingly.  I do this for everything like images etc...